# How to go from one page to another in django

Tags: django, django-models, django-forms, django-templates, django-views

I'm new to Django and python (infact my first language which I've only been learning for 3 months)
I'm creating this website using Django and I'm not able to go from one page to another using the href tag. it throws at me a 404 error saying "current path didn't match any of these"

This is my code

views.py

```
from django.shortcuts import render
from django.http import HttpResponseRedirect
from .models import off
# Create your views here.

def homepage(request):
    return render(request=request,
                  template_name='main/home.html',
                  context={'toll' : off.objects.all})
def secondpage(request):
    return render(request = request,
                  template_name = 'main/next.html')
```

main/urls.py

```
from django.urls import path
from . import views

app_name = 'main'

urlpatterns = [
    path('',views.homepage,name='homepage'),
    path('',views.secondpage,name='secondpage')
]
```

templates/mains/home.html

```
<div class="topnav">
  <a href="{% url 'next' %}">Link </a>
  <a href="#">Link </a>
  <a href="#">Link </a>
</div>
```

I also request the helper to simply it for me as I wouldn't be able to handle complex and advanced python terminology

Thanks In Advance From a Friend

Arvind

Answer (score 0):

I think you should read [this](https://www.djangoproject.com/start/) to start with Django.